# measuring microseconds a process runs in Linux

Tags: linux, time

I'm looking to get the number of microseconds that a process takes to execute. Does anybody know how to do this on a Linux system? (I'm looking for a time value more accurate than milliseconds, because I'm measuring something very sensitive.)

NOTE: I don't think the time command will work to the accuracy I'm looking for... it seems to only go down to milliseconds, which isn't really good enough for my purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [PAPI](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/). btw, [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182554/microsecond-accurate-or-better-process-timing-in-linux)'s a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say whether this is your own code and you want to time some part of it internally. You also don't say what it is you're actually trying to accomplish.

One thing you might be doing is running some program in the shell. If so, the most straightforward way is to time a loop of multiple calls to the process and do the math.

Bash:

```
t=($({ time -p for i in {1..1000000}; do some_prog; done; } 2>&1))
echo "scale=6;${t[1]}/1000000" | bc
```

If your `date` command (and system) support nanoseconds and you don't mind the overhead:

```
begin=$(date +%s.%N); some_prog; end=$(date +%s.%N); echo "scale=6; $end - $begin" | bc
```

Comment: +1: this is a much better solution than trying to precisely time an individual run, as it averages out lots of potential sources of error which would otherwise make a sub-millisecond timing unreliable

Answer (score 1):

**Linux `perf` CLI tool**

Times of the order of microsecond are just noise in a modern system.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182554/microsecond-accurate-or-better-process-timing-in-linux asks if there is any way to reduce variability produced by the kernel.

The `perf` CLI tool does print microseconds and more, and that will allow us to see just how such measurements are just noise.

Ubuntu 22.04 setup:

```
sudo apt install linux-tools-common linux-tools-generic
echo -1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid
```

x86 assembly program that loops `CYCLES` cycles:

main.S

```
.text
.global _start
_start:
    mov $0, %rax
    mov $CYCLES, %rcx
.Lloop_label:
    inc %rax
    loop .Lloop_label

    /* exit */
    mov $60, %rax   /* syscall number */
    mov $0, %rdi    /* exit status */
    syscall
```

Assemble and run:

```
cpp -DCYCLES=100000 main.S main.cpp.S
as -o main.o main.cpp.S
ld -o main.out main.o
perf stat ./main.out
```

Some sample results on my Lenovo ThinkPad P51:

| `CYCLES` | seconds time elapsed |
| --- | --- |
| 10^9 | 1.3 s |
| 10^8 | 0.13 s |
| 10^7 | 0.014 s |
| 10^6 | 1.9 ms |
| 10^5 | 0.6 - 0.8 ms |
| 10^4 | 0.4 - 0.8 ms |

From this we see that numbers down to the millisecond were somehow meaningful and scaled with size somewhat: 10x less cycles meant 10x less time.

But somewhere around the 0.1 ms thigs stopped scaling completely, and instead of program execution we must be measuring something else completely random.

You could also try to create baremetal programs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054578/how-to-run-a-program-without-an-operating-system/32483545#32483545 I wonder how much noise the BIOS and hardware itself create in such cases, would be an interesting thing to try out.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586354/linux-time-command-microseconds-or-better-accuracy

Answer (score 0):

`times(2)` returns the process times in jiffies, not time. As such it can only measure units of time as finely as the frequency of your kernel. `clock_gettime(2)` can do finer resolutions if the kernel is compiled properly, but there's no easy-to-use userland interface to it.